# SED works in shell but not in Script

Tags: sed

```
 cat test.txt
```

host01-pc.local

```
 i=host01-pc.local
 sed -i "/$i/d" ./test.txt
 cat test.txt
```

so this works in the shell, but when i run it in my script

```
readarray PC < ./test.txt

for i in "${PC[@]}";
do

        ping -c 1 -W 20 $i

        if [ $? -eq 0 ];
                then echo -e "$i is reachable";
                sed -i "/$i/d" ./test.txt

        else
                        
                        echo -e "$i no ping"

        fi
done
```

I get the error message

sed: -e expression #1, char 26: unterminated address regex

Comment: At a guess, it's the newlines in your array - try adding `-t` to your `readarray` command

Comment: Why don't you use something like `fping` instead?  `fping <test.txt`.

Comment: Wouldn't be surprised they're doing this on some distros without it and don't want to install it (`fping` isn't already part of most distros unless you only take into account latest/updated ones) @Kusalananda

Comment: Ill try that fping out, i am using a standard centos 7 distro, should of mentioned that earlier. Ty and Ty you steeldriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing whether it is a washed down version of something much bigger, I only modified a minimum amount of details in your original scripts. Tested on GNU Bash.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
readarray -t arr < test.txt
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
    if ping -c 1 -W 20 "$i" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "$i is reachable"
        sed -i "/$i/d" test.txt
    else
        echo "$i no ping"
    fi
done
```

***** Credit goes to @steeldriver for his comment concerning the `-t` flag added to `readarray`.